# C++: Platform independent game lib?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I want to write a serious 2D game, and it would be nice if I have a version for Linux and one for Windows (and eventually OSX). Java is fantastic because it is platform independent. But Java is too slow to write a serious game. So, I thought to write it in C++. But C++ isn't very cross-platform friendly. I can find game libraries for Windows and libraries for Linux, but I'm searching one that I can use for both, by recompiling the source on a Windows platform and on a Linux platform.

Are there engines for this or is this idea irrelevant? Isn't it that easy (recompiling)?

Any advice and information about C++ libraries would be very very very appreciated!

Comment: "But Java is to slow to write a serious game."  [I disagree](http://www.runescape.com/) (to an extent).

Comment: You may get some useful answers from the SO question [Game Programming Library C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90272/game-programming-library-c).

Comment: Modern java is actually on-par with C/C++ in terms of runtime speed, and it's SO much faster to develop in. Do the research. And make sure any article you're looking at was written recently.

Comment: IL2 Sturmovik (flight simulator) was written in java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl) (in association with c/c++), it's great for 2D games (and supports 3D through opengGL), and it works on windows, os x and linux.

Answer (score 2):

I have use [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org) to build simple games.  In its own words

> SFML is a portable and easy to use
>   multimedia API written in C++. You can
>   see it as a modern, object-oriented
>   alternative to SDL. SFML is composed
>   of several packages to perfectly suit
>   your needs. You can use SFML as a
>   minimal windowing system to interface
>   with OpenGL, or as a fully-featured
>   multimedia library for building games
>   or interactive programs.

I really like it as it's definitely a C++ library, not C written as C++.

However, you asked about 2D engines, I've yet to find a good one. SFML and SDL are more low level media libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For 2D games I recommend [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org). It's similar in concept to SDL, having most of the same capabilities, but is much more C++ oriented (SDL is a C library), and because it uses OpenGL internally, it performs better in most cases. Besides that, in my opinion, it is much easier to use.